# Getting video record of Travis-CI builds with TestFairy

Tags: java, android, apk, travis-ci, testfairy

I use a FrameLayout with a recyclerView and a linearView where I ask for Runtime permissions. 
I have tests for Runtime permissions with UiAutomator that pass locally but that failed with Travis-CI. 
These tests are for an Activity that uses user location. I implemented the Runtime permission with`ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(...), ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(...) and onRequestPermissionsResult(...)`
I want to get video of the build/tests that are performed on Travis-CI because it seems the activity is not correctly displayed (can't find allow/deny buttons).
I got advised to use TestFairy. 
I am trying to deploy Travis build to TestFairy to get videos of the tests using https://docs.testfairy.com/Continuous_Integration/Travis_CI.html.

`deploy:
   provider: testfairy //ok
   api-key: "TESTFAIRY API KEY" //ok
   app-file: Path to the app file (APK/IPA) // what to put here?`

What should I put under app-file? I have a android project using Gradle. I found several apk in /app/build/outputs/apk

I seems for android we also need to sign our app. I didn't do since this is just a class project, not real use application. I this part mandatory ?

`keystore-file: Path to your keystore-file
 storepass: storepass
 alias: alias`

Is this the right thing to do for sign in this case ? https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `keystore-file` anymore, see an [updated documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/testfairy).

Regarding which "app-file" to use, it depend on your Gradle config, TestFairy will accept any APK that can be installed on a device, so it should be signed (even if it a debug keystore)